# Format JSON with new keys from value after sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json, object

I am trying to rewrite some of my existing python code in Nodejs. However, I am having some trouble with data types as I am used to creating dictionary in python which is not available in Nodejs. Basically I am getting data from our database using psycopg2 (getting rows from cur.fetchall()) which returns the result as below.

```
##Column names: Snapshot_day, Bucket, Sub_Bucket, Bucket_Flag, Issue_Reason,  Reason_Description, first_violation_date, dw_create_date, dw_update_date, area,  region
rows = (("2021-04-05", "Virginia", "Vir123", "Yes", "Connection Issue", "Connection Issue", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-17", "EC", "AMER"),
         ("2020-01-05", "New York", "POR532", "No", "Server", "Failure", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-17", "EC", "AMER"),
         ("2020-01-05", "Virginia", "Vir543", "Yes", "Server", "Failure", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-17", "2020-02-17", "EC", "AMER")
        )
```

I am using a for loop and if condition within these rows (tuples) to assign Snapshot_day, bucket, sub_bucket and Issue reason as keys and finally sorting it in ascending order.

Fast forward, my final output looks like below. Running python code [here](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wxwz29ak)

```
{"2020-01-05":{"Virginia":{"Vir543":{"Yes":{"Issue_Reason":"Server","Reason_Description":"Failure","area":"WC","dw_create_date":"2020-01-17","dw_update_date":"2020-02-17","first_violation_date":"2020-01-17","region":"AMER"}}},"New York":{"POR532":{"No":{"Issue_Reason":"Server","Reason_Description":"Failure","area":"EC","dw_create_date":"2020-01-17","dw_update_date":"2020-01-17","first_violation_date":"2020-01-17","region":"AMER"}}}},"2021-04-05":{"Virginia":{"Vir123":{"Yes":{"Issue_Reason":"Connection Issue","Reason_Description":"Connection Issue","area":"EC","dw_create_date":"2020-01-17","dw_update_date":"2020-01-17","first_violation_date":"2020-01-17","region":"AMER"}}}}}
```

I am trying to get similar output in Nodejs. I was able to pull the data from the database using pg library. I have my output as below, but  I havent been able to figure out how I can get the JSON output as my python file.

```
##Output from my Javascript
##Column names: Snapshot_day, Bucket, Sub_Bucket, Bucket_Flag, Issue_Reason,  Reason_Description, first_violation_date, dw_create_date, dw_update_date, area,  region
[
  [
    '2021-04-05',
    'Virginia',
    'Vir123',
    'Yes',
    'Connection Issue',
    'Connection Issue',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    'EC',
    'AMER'
  ],
  [
    '2020-01-05',
    'New York',
    'POR532',
    'No',
    'Server',
    'Failure',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    'EC',
    'AMER'
  ],
  [
    '2020-01-05',
    'Virginia',
    'Vir543',
    'Yes',
    'Server',
    'Failure',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-02-17',
    'EC',
    'AMER'
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// dbOutput represents your database output
const dbOutput = [
  [
    '2021-04-05',
    'Virginia',
    'Vir123',
    'Yes',
    'Connection Issue',
    'Connection Issue',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    'EC',
    'AMER'
  ],
  [
    '2020-01-05',
    'New York',
    'POR532',
    'No',
    'Server',
    'Failure',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    'EC',
    'AMER'
  ],
  [
    '2020-01-05',
    'Virginia',
    'Vir543',
    'Yes',
    'Server',
    'Failure',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-01-17',
    '2020-02-17',
    'EC',
    'AMER'
  ]
]
// reduce the array into an object
const obj = dbOutput.reduce((map,data)=>{
 const [date,province,code,flag,issueReason,reasonDescription,createDate,updateDate,violationDate,area,region] = data
if(!map[date]){
  map[date]={}
}
if(!map[date][province]){
 map[date][province]={}
}
if(!map[date][province][code]){
map[date][province][code]={}
}
if(!map[date][province][code][flag]){
map[date][province][code][flag]={}
}
map[date][province][code][flag]={
'Issue_Reason':issueReason,
'Reason_Description':reasonDescription,
area,
region,
'dc_create_date':createDate,
'dc_update_date':updateDate,
}
return map
},{})
//get the sorted date keys of the object then reduce the sorted keys array into an the final output 
const output = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b)=> new Date(a) - new Date(b)).reduce((map,date) =>{
 map[date]={...obj[date]}
return map
},{})
console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```